# How to use the underlying type of an object when passing it as a generic argument

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have a message broker service that dispatches messages from various components in code. It relies on an attribute that defines which methods handle which messages.

The meat and potatoes of the service comes down to the `HandleMessage` method:

```
private void HandleMessage<TMessage, TSender>(TMessage message, TSender sender = null) where TMessage : Message where TSender : class
{
    var messageType = message.GetType();
    if (messageHandlers.TryGetValue(messageType, out List<Delegate> handlers))
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
        {
            try
            {
                if (handler is Action<TSender, TMessage> h)
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => h.Invoke(sender, message));
                else
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => handler.DynamicInvoke(sender, message));
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                log?.LogError($"Attempt to handle a message failed. {e.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        log?.LogError(string.Format("No handler found for message of type {0}", messageType.FullName));
        throw new NoHandlersException(messageType.FullName);
    }
}
```

A feature that is important to me is *not* having to cast the sender *or* the message in the handler methods themselves, so when a handler is "registered", it is registered as an `Action<T1,T2>` where T1 and 2 are the *specific types* the handler accepts.

When sending messages between components (in process), everything works great because the type of a message is (usually) known at compile time and thus it's type can be specific (I.E. not the base `Message` class that all messages inherit from)

However, I need to support messages arriving over the network. They arrive serialized with a type code in the header. So there is *no way* to know until runtime what type of message will be arriving.

Simply put, when a message arrives over the network, `TMessage` in the `HandleMessage` method is type `Message`, and *not* the *specific* message type that was deserialized.

This causes the pattern match (`if (handler is Action<TSender, TMessage> h)`) to fail and forces me to use `DynamicInvoke`.

Is there any way I can "coerce" the generic type to be the *specific* type of the message?

Answer (score 0):

Try having TMessage be of type BrokeredMessage through a constraint on the generic, and then using:

```
var ct = brokeredMessage.ContentType;
Type bodyType = Type.GetType(ct, true);
```

to get the actual type.